# ¿Cómo lanzo una animación en Unity3d 5?

Tags: unity3d

Tengo 2 objetos, uno que cuando colisiona dispare la animación del otro... pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision){
    Debug.Log ("yaaa");
    abre = false;
}
```

Tengo eso en el Animator del otro, es el que Lanza la animation pero cuando hay colisión no pasa nada y no sé cómo hacerlo en Unity 5. ¿Cómo sería?

Comment: Tienes agregado Rigidbody y Colliders a ambos objetos? Esta activa la pestaña Trigger del que tiene el script?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usar un `OnCollisionEnter`, ejemplo:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
  abre = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si cada uno de los objetos tiene su propio animator, seria necesario obtener el animator del objeto que colisiona. Creo que son dos opciones en tu caso:

**Caso 1: Trigger**

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) {
    Anim colliderAnimator = col.GetComponent<Animator>();

    colliderAnimator.setBool("cerrar", true);
}
```

Por otra parte, recuerda que el Collider que use tu objeto (BoxCollider, CapsuleCollider, etc) DEBE estar marcado para funcionar como Trigger.

**Caso 2: Collision:**

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
        Anim colliderAnimator = col.collider.GetComponent<Animator>();

        colliderAnimator.setBool("cerrar", true);
}
```

En este caso no hace falta que marques el collider como trigger (por eso utilizamos el metodo OnCollisionEnter()). El objeto Collision contiene un collider (el objeto con el que colisionas), y de el obtenemos el animator.

EN general, lo que estoy haciendo en ambos casos es cojer el Componente animator del objeto con el que estas colisionando. A continuacion, activamos la animacion con el parametro "cerrar" a true. He supuesto este caso (no especificas como se llama la animacion que quieres ejecutar).

Por ultimo, **Recuerda**: El animator del Objeto, debe tener un parametro (por ej: cerrar) y una transicion de los estados que necesites al de tu animacion, cuando el parametro cambie de valor.